# Restore default folder chmod

Tags: filesystem, chmod

I entered `/var/www` and I ran `sudo find / -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;`, thinking that this will only affect folders in `/var/www`. This changed permissions of all system folders.

How can I restore every folder to its default permissions?

Comment: Re-installation only think I can think of now...

Comment: If you chose to reinstall, you may want to back up your data first, such as the `/var/www` folder, as well as `/home` so that you can restore it after re-installation.  But you will still have to verify the permissions of all the files after you restore.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall is only option. sorry :).

Comment: Reinstall is not the ONLY option, however, it is the easiest to be honest.